# Restore Wordpress on Localhost Xampp

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I've got a folder of WP with folders like: cron, db, dns, mail, pam, user_dir, vesta, web. Every tutorial I see has different folders and files for restore. In db folder I have mysql file(24mb) for import. So I create a db and try to import it. It says Incorrect format parameter. I have no idea what to do and how to restore WP on Xampp. Please guide me

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: wordpress folders don't include any of the folders you mention... can you add a screenshot of the file tree to your question?

Comment: Just did put the screenshot

Comment: I suppose wordpress files are inside the "web" folder

Comment: Inside web folder you should find a file tree like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pm0Cd.png

Comment: I put screen of web folder and one of the folders. the archive inside folder is empty. the other folder has similar files

Comment: it seems there is not any wordpress file in the images you posted

Comment: Ok. What about the db?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171375/discussion-between-dafois-and-dima-rashevskiy).